# Is there any way to declare class dynamically on Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, compile-time

I just think about this case, I want to declare a class C which extends from other classes dynamically.
Suppose that I have class A and class B. Now, I want the class C extends A or B base on a specified condition such as:

```
#ifdef USE_CLASS_A
class C: A
#else 
Class C: B
#endif
```

How can I do this in Objective-C?

UPDATE: I just need dynamic at compile time, not runtime. I mean, during compiling time, the class C will  extend A or B. This extending will be go forever, don't change at runtime.

Comment: I don't think you can, but it seems a rather unmaintainable approach to me.

Comment: why you are looking for such approach

Comment: No you can't. What are you going to achieve? There may be better structures available that serve your purpose. Are you going to simulate multiple inheritance? If so then you should get familiar with protocols.

Comment: Well, strictly spoken, that thing with the #ifdef could work of course. But that is not dynamic at runtime but rather static at compiletime.

Comment: You might have CA extending A and CB extending B. In your programm you could then dynamically decide whether to create an CA or an CB object. You may store the references in a variable of type id. (not id*, because id is already a reference - unlike other class references). However, before actually accessing properties or methods you would have to test (`if [myObject isKindOfClass:[CA class]]' or so) and then assign myObject to a temp varialbe of type CA* before actually accessing members. However, I believe that - in most cases - a protocoll would suite your needs best.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my question. I just want the class C extern from A or B dynamically at compile time.

Comment: Yes, Protocol suites my needs. But I don't want to check the condition with if...else many time in my source. So I am trying to find a solution, which I just need to check 1 time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your update the answer is yes - using `#if`/`#ifdef` you can determine at compile time whether class C extends class A or class B in exactly the way you have suggested.

Of course classes A & B better provide same set of common methods and your code only call those methods, or else you will need further conditional code (compile or runtime) at the points you use class C.

Comment: I have tested this and it works. But my Technical Architect recommend that I shouldn't use macro.